# mysql query for my project (It has only 1 table named judge_review) which needs to sort out top 3 winners

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried writing the below query but i just need 3 winners(1st,2nd and 3rd place) and my query has just brought every project in descending order but i need only top 3.

```
<SELECT judge_review.sub_ID, SUM(judge_review.avgPoints) AS TOTAL FROM judge_review GROUP BY judge_review.sub_ID ORDER BY TOTAL DESC>
```

[image]

Comment: `SELECT judge_review.sub_ID, SUM(judge_review.avgPoints) AS TOTAL FROM judge_review GROUP BY judge_review.sub_ID ORDER BY TOTAL DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `LIMIT 3`

```
SELECT judge_review.sub_ID,
       SUM(judge_review.avgPoints) AS TOTAL 
       FROM judge_review 
       GROUP BY judge_review.sub_ID 
       ORDER BY TOTAL DESC 
       LIMIT 3
```

Reference:- [Limit Data Selections From a MySQL Database](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Answer (score 1):

To limit number of returned rows in the result set you have to specify number of that rows by adding to the end of the query `LIMIT 3`.